# Is it normal to experience long load time accessing your website on heroku?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When I try to access https://boiling-bastion-xxxx.herokuapp.com/, it takes about 5 seconds or more to load. Is that normal?

Once it loads, it runs fine. I'm talking about actually accessing the link for the first time. Is this the same for others as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is completely normal.

There's information about it on devcenter.heroku.com: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling

If your application has one hour of inactivity your web dyno will idle out. If you access your application after one hour the web dyno will wake up again, causing a few seconds of delay.

**Important**:
This is only a problem when you have one (free) web dyno. If you have more then 1 web dyno running you will never face these troubles.